# Modify user password without knowing the existing one

Tags: python, ldap

I want to create a script for changing user password but without knowing the existing password, so it's like the reseting the password to new one.

Here is my script using python with ldap3

```
from ldap3 import *
server = Server('myldapserver.com', get_info=ALL)
the_user = 'cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com'
conn = Connection(server, the_user, password='adminpass')
conn.bind()

user = 'cn=testuser,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com'
conn.extend.microsoft.modify_password('cn=testuser,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com', None, 'newpassword')
print(conn.result)
```

But it gave me the error:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPAttributeError: invalid attribute type in attribute
```

If someone could help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to change a password in an Active Directory domain.
First of all you must check the result of the bind() method. If bind is not successful you get an anonymous connection and you can't do anything with the password attribute.

Also you must establish a secure connection to change the password, try to set use_ssl=True in the server object, or try conn.start_tls() after conn.bind().

Last but more important the new password is the second parameter of the modify_password() not the third.